# Generic Java Platform EE

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm just getting started with getting informed with Java's EE and am reviewing the content at:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE

There appears to be many products on the market that support this platform. What I would like to know is whether there is just a generic version of EE that can be used for developing and whether Eclipse can be used with it as well. Also, is the generic version of EE free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can develop Java EE with with [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). You can even download a version with Java EE plugins directly bundled.

There are plenty of severs where you can run J2EE applications such as Tomcat if you only need a JSP container or you can use JBoss, Glassfish... a complete Java EE application servers. Those are free and they are not the only ones.

**EDIT**

Maybe I made a confusion between generic and free but Java EE is primarily a specification. Glassfish is the implementation that Sun (Oracle now) created as kind of example.